# What are the codes(like MEID) related to CDMA phones?

Tags: java-me

What are the codes related to CDMA phones? Like we have IMSI,IMEI,CellID in GSM,do we have any such codes that can be retrieved from a CDMA phone?
And can anyone suggest how to retrieve them from a phone(programatically)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still no standard J2ME telephony API, so either see what the cbs connection in JSR-120 can give you or use system properties.

I would suggest trying to retrieve the same codes on a GSM phone and on a CDMA phone. It might just work.

To retrieve the IMEI, look at:

[Getting Device IMEI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680782/getting-device-imei/681033#681033)