# Get device unique ID

Tags: java, java-me, midp, imei

Is there a way to get a device's unique identification using MIDP2.0?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680782/getting-device-imei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need to get the IMEI number of the device.

According to the information I found there is no J2ME method to do that because the Hardware API is different from a one model to another. But the device manufacturers provide APIs to get the IMEI number.

Have a look on following article.

[Get device ID](http://mobilepit.com/10/how-to-get-imei-number-in-j2me-javame.html)