# How to get Device IMEI in Java ME?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I have a problem getting the device IMEI in J2me, I have tried all the strings in those posts, and also case sensitive but I always get null

[Getting Device IMEI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680782/getting-device-imei)

http://qa.java-samples.com/questions/742/how-to-get-the-imei-number-of-the-mobile

Comment: when I try microedition.platform I got Nokia C2, but it also give me null in Device IMEI

Comment: Note that many devices require the midlet to be signed for the imei-properties to work.

Comment: which device you are using @AmiraElsayedIsmail ?

Comment: @Lucifer : I'm using Nokia C2 Device

Comment: @Petrus : It is not a commercial application now I just want to use it for testing something so if you please can tell me how can I sign it free I will be thankful, and I will also search for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like:

```
Nokia
System.getProperty("phone.imei");
System.getProperty("com.nokia.imei");
System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.imei"); //especially for S40  devices
```

Note: Requires signed MIDlet. S60 3rd edition device does not requires signing to fetch this info.On Series 40 phones this requires that your MIDlet is signed to either operator or manufacturer domain, and this is only available in Series 40 3rd Edition, FP1 devices and newer.

```
Sony Ericsson
System.getProperty("com.sonyericsson.imei");

Samsung
System.getProperty("com.samsung.imei");

Motorola
System.getProperty("IMEI");

System.getProperty("com.motorola.IMEI");

Siemens
System.getProperty("com.siemens.IMEI");



LG
System.getProperty("com.lge.imei");
```

Comment: I have tried all of them and they give me null value when I run them on the device

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail, have you signed your aplication ?

Comment: no I'm in the testing stage and I want to test it first on the device and make sure it is running, before sign it