# How to Get IMEI or Serial Number for Android 10+

Tags: android, android-10.0, serial-number, imei

As we need to fetch IMEI or Serial No for all Android specially of 10+ but same was restricted for google due to policy issue. As our application need IMEI number to share with operator to block handset in case of lost. Operators have only IMEI number from where they can fetch exact detail but i am stuck in between as operator is demanding IMEI number although same was restricted for Android 10+. Kindly Help me to out from this situation for valid answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Device IMEI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680782/getting-device-imei)

Comment: check this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173823/i-am-getting-imei-null-in-android-q) hope it will help you